# Control for common factors

Tags: regression, estimation, causality, mediation

Hi I have a question about how to control for common factors.

I used people of a state as the sample to investigate a causal relation between two variables, y and x.
Although there are a lot of studies suggest that y is influenced by x and I used exactly same regression method to estimate the relation, my sample does not show the association I expected.

Here, I found that the state I used has a unique culture that can affect y. (I tested the existence statistically)
Therefore, I conjecture that the relation between y and x is dominated by the common cultural factor in the state.

In this case, is there any method to control for the common factor?

Thank you for your time spent to read this question.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Note that your username, identicon, & a link to your user page 
are automatically added to every post you make, so there is no need to sign 
your posts. In fact, we prefer you don't.

Comment: Do you observe y and x in the other states? Or do you just have the culture variable for the full set?